# Add theme support custom header will not hide text?

Tags: add-theme-support

I am having problems with `add_theme_support('custom-header');` I can change the Header Text color but I **can't hide** my Header Text when I leave unchecked **"Show header text with your image"** inside admin panel (obviously it should hide header text if unchecked). I have no idea should I add some specific CSS for this to work or do I have to change my functions.php? Any thoughts or suggestions? My functions.php for header support looks like this:

```
//Code for custom header support
$defaults = array(
'default-image'          => '',
'random-default'         => false,
'width'                  => 750,
'height'                 => 100,
'flex-height'            => true,
'flex-width'             => true,
'default-text-color'     => '#FF0000',
'header-text'            => true,
'uploads'                => true,
'wp-head-callback'       => '',
'admin-head-callback'    => '',
'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $defaults );
```

CSS looks like this:

```
a:link, a:visited{
text-decoration: none; 
color: #000000;
}

a:hover{
color: #5f5f5f;
}

h1{
  font-size: 54px;
}

#header  h1{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added this code to my header.php and it worked nicely:

```
#header a{
<?php if(get_header_textcolor()=='blank') { 
echo 'visibility: hidden;'; } else { 
?> 
color:#<?php echo get_header_textcolor();  } ?>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, the theme you are using does not take into account the Custom header settings when it puts in the Site Title and Description.

I would suggest (if you are comfortable in PHP) creating a child theme ([as described here](http://designisphilosophy.com/24-days-of-wordpress/creating-a-wordpress-child-theme-the-smart-way/)) for your theme, then copy header.php into your child theme and remove/alter the area where it puts in your Site Header.

For more great tips on WordPress basics, the same guy covers a lot in his [24 Days of WordPress series](http://designisphilosophy.com/tutorials/24-days-of-wordpress-the-wordpress-advent-calendar/).

Comment: To be honest this is my first theme I build from scratch and I know that I can solve that problem by using Settings API but  just wanted to know if there is a easier way for making this work. So it looks like Settings API is a way to go with this one...

Comment: That's great. If it's a "from-sratch" child theme, then you can just dig into your header.php and work with that :).

Answer (score 0):

@Dejo Dekic
This solution worked! for example, if you need to show the header text only when you enable(check) it, then in header.php you should have a code like this:

```
<?php if(get_header_textcolor()!='blank') { ?>
<!-- here is just a good example of a normal header text -->
<a href="<?php echo home_url();?>" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:20px;color:#<?php echo get_header_textcolor();?>!important;"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dejo's solution works , but not placing h1 and h2 tags is bad for SEO_

This is why normal WP installation just hides it leaving it in it's place,
in this way it will remain visible to spiders;

For ex.:
Twenty14 theme relies on filteringCSS to hide Header-Text,
take a look at  custom-header.php (line69 -  twentyfourteen)

```
    // Has the text been hidden?
    if ( ! display_header_text() ) :
?>
    .site-title,
    .site-description {
        clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE7 */
        clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
        position: absolute;
    }
<?php
    // If the user has set a custom color for the text, use that.
    elseif ( $text_color != get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-color' ) ) :
?>
    .site-title a {
        color: #<?php echo esc_attr( $text_color ); ?>;
    }
<?php endif; ?>
```

so if you want to use this function place the right .site-title & .site-description markup (if you don't know look at twenty14 header.php)_

by the way using clip:rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) is like looking at something a rectangular screen with no height or width ,(awesome solution!!!)_